# Keep order of addresses sent for geocoding

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, geocoding, here-api

I'm developing a Here Maps based we application.

The user can upload a .xls spreadsheet file to plan directions. These files can have up to 1000 geographically correct addresses.

If I'm correct, to be able to plan a route with these addresses, I first need to geocode them all, using Here Maps' geocoding service:

```
function geoCodeUploadedAddresses() {
    for(var i = 0; i< uploadedWaypoints.length; i++) {
     nokia.places.search.manager.geoCode({
     searchTerm :  uploadedWaypoints[i],
     onComplete:  onGeocodeComplete
    }); 
    }

}

function onGeocodeComplete(data, requestStatus, requestId) {
    if (requestStatus == "OK") {        
        console.log(data);
    } else if(requestStatus == "ERROR") {
        console.log("error")
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't return the addresses in the same order they were sent.

For example, the `uploadedWaypoints` array before geocoding:

1. 1081 Budapest, Blaha Lujza tér
2. 2119 Pécel, Lázár Vilmos utca
3. 1214 Budapest, Szent Imre tér

After geocoding the addresses come back in a completely random order:

Ex.:

1. 2119 Pécel, Lázár Vilmos utca
2. 1081 Budapest, Blaha Lujza tér
3. 1214 Budapest, Szent Imre tér

So how can I geocode all of these addresses while keeping the same order they were in the array?

Comment: You can't.  You're making a series of individual HTTP requests; there's no way to make the responses come back in any particular order.  You'll need to match them up with your original data, or find a batch API that's better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create request using `jsoncallback` parameter and generate a different callback dynamically for each request so you can match with every request you're doing.

See the documentation:

http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-geocode.html

***jsoncallback***

xs:string - Specifies the name of a user-defined function used to wrap the JSON response.

Also, 1000 geocoding operations on the client side is a lot to do and it might take a long time. Also there are restrictions associated to the type of key you're using and so you might be facing the limitations in terms of requests you can do on a specific 24h period.

You might be interested in Batch geocoding in the Here for Enterprise offer that would be better in your case.

Comment: Thank you. I finally went with the Batch API, thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

[async library](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback) seems to suit your needs.

Here is how you could implement it.

```
var getGeoCode = function(waypoint, callback) {
    nokia.places.search.manager.geoCode({
        searchTerm :  waypoint,
        onComplete:  function(data, requestStatus, requestId) {
                         if (requestStatus == "OK") {        
                             callback(null, data);
                         } else if(requestStatus == "ERROR") {
                             // You can either call with error to break pending calls or some error value - callback({error : requestStatus});
                             console.log("error");
                             callback(null, data);
                         }
                         // You need to callback on other cases too.
                     }
    });
};


async.map(uploadedWaypoints, 
          getGeoCode,
          function(err, results){
               // results is now an array of geocodes for each address
          }
);
```

Also quoting from the docs:

> ... since this function applies the iterator to each item in parallel there
>   is no guarantee that the iterator functions will complete in order,
>   however the results array will be in the same order as the original
>   array.

Just showing you the way how to get ordered results. Ideally, you should look into bulk geocoding services.

HTH.